# Having issue with Http Response in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular5

I am learning angular 5 from scratch. I have some issue with Http Response. I could not fetch data with get().

```
      getRecipes() {this.http.get('https://indhu-project-45b73.firebaseio.com/recipes.json')
          .subscribe(response => {
           const recipes: Recipe[] = response;
          this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
          });
```

i have provided the imports as,

```
  import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
  import {RecipeService} from '../recipes/recipe.service';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import {Recipe} from '../recipes/recipe.model';
```

also

```
  setRecipes(recipes: Recipe[]) {
   this.recipes = recipes;
   this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice());
   }
```

I know there must be some basic mistakes from my end. Can Someone help me in this. I am getting this following error

```
     "Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Recipe[]'.
      The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you 
       mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      src/app/shared/data-storage.service.ts(17,15): error TS2322: Type 
      'Object' is not assignable to type 'Recipe[]'.
       The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you 
        mean to use the 'any' type instead?
        Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'."
```

Comment: Your http code looks ok. Looks like a Typescript error. Can you try this.http.get<Recipe[]>(....)

Comment: thank You, But where exactly you want me to change and try

Comment: in the getRecipes method  change this.http.get(..) to this.http.get<Recipe[]>(..)

Comment: it is not throwing error , but the output is not working

Comment: Oh no! Sorry, it is working Fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the type of your response is *Object* so you can't assign it to recipes of type *Recipe[].*
You can use type *'any'* for your response instead. It will work then.

```
getRecipes() {this.http.get('https://indhu-project-45b73.firebaseio.com/recipes.json')
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
       const recipes: Recipe[] = response;
      this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, do u want me to add,

.subscribe((response: Response<any>) => {
        const recipes: Recipe[] = response;
        this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
      });

this i snot working either

Comment: No just use the code above and let me know if it is working.